# Should I use "page" or "screen" word in Toast messages?

Tags: android, terminology

When I refer to Android screen I usually use two words "page" and "screen". This page word probably remained from the web development.

Now, when I want do display a `Toast` message to a user, should I say something like "You are currently on this page" or "You are currently on this screen"?

Comment: You could use Activity... but maybe that's just for developers

Comment: @colegu A user will not understand this. This is mainly developers' term

Comment: This is not directly a programming question and therefore OT; would fit ux.stackexchange.com or similar sites better. Apart from that: I don't see the point within doing this. The user should see on which "page" he is given on the layout and so on. What's the point in telling him in an extra toast in the first place? If you have to do that your UI is not optimal and intuitive. (or I miss an obvious scenario here)

Comment: @alextsc I agree. But there are rare situations when a user is on the text page where neither text or the title say where he is. Then on certain press, a user should know where he is. This has also been the first time I've used such feature.

Comment: Well, yeah that's what I mean when I say not optimal. You should rather get a title or similar features in there in this case. Just imagine where people use phones and their apps, they might open the app and someone starts talking to them. 10 seconds later they are finished and focus on the app again and they missed the toast. Now they have no idea where they are. A fixed help is way better.

Comment: @alextsc I agree with you. But as I said, I cannot do anything here. I am just coding other person's design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't write "page" because page just belongs to the web development in my opinion. So you could choose "screen" or just take another sentence like "You currently see ...", "What you see here..."

This is what I think but you display a Toast it could be that the user doesn't read it.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of developer You should use the term "Activity" for a screen, From the user prospective it should  "You are currently on this screen".

Thanks 
Om